# Difference between C-T and C-o in vim?

Tags: vim

These 2 vim keyboard shortcuts seems for similar purpose, `<C-T>` goes back previous tag in the history, and `<C-o>` goes to previous entry in the jump list. Any difference between these 2?

Comment: @jww - This question is within the boundaries defined within the [help] under the [What topics can I ask about here?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) section. "`...software tools commonly used by programmers; and is
a practical, answerable problem that is unique to software development`".

Comment: @Lix - its useless criteria. Nearly all software on a computer is used by developers. The OP is going to have to try a little harder to bring it back into the programming realm. Or he should take it to a site that's tailored for the question.

Comment: @jww - we're not talking about any old software... Vim in this case it being used as an IDE hence it **is** a "problem that is unique to software development".

Comment: @jww - by your logic any other post talking about sublime or visual studio is also off-topic - they are not.

Comment: FYI, I am experimenting some C programming with ctags and just confused about these 2 keyboard shortcuts. I assumed it is more appropriate to ask it here since vim is usually considered as a programming editor. BTW: there were many vim configuration related questions in the past.

Comment: @Thomson - the fact that questions were asked in the past is not really a good point to use as the types of posts that are allowed or considered "good" change as the opinions of the site users change over time.

Comment: You are correct in your statement that VIM would be considered a programming tool - it most certainly is. By this logic, and by the statements in the [help], your post was made in the right place. It would have most likely be accepted on [su] as well - but that doesn't make it off-topic for [so].

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The tag stack is populated only when you jump to a tag using something like `:tag foo` or `<c-]>`. This means that you can do any number of non-tag-related jumps between your `<C-]>`s and `<C-t>`s without altering the tag stack and be pretty confident that `<C-t>` will *always* jump you to the latest *tag* you visited and from where.

The jump list, on the other hand, will record all the jumps you did between your tag-related jumps so `<C-o>` will usually take quite a few more attempts to go back to where you want to go than `<C-t>`.

Think about `<C-o>` as a "catchall" way to go back and `<C-t>` as more specialized version of `<C-o>`.